# Saving WorkItem#IterationPath on newly created Iteration

Tags: c#, tfs, iteration, workitem

I can successfully create an iteration path via:

```
var commonservice = collection.GetService<ICommonStructureService>();

// create new area path and iteration path
var iterationRoot = commonservice.GetNodeFromPath("\\MyTeamProject\\Iteration");
var newIterationPath = commonservice.CreateNode("my new sprint", iterationRoot.Uri);
```

However, when I try and assign this path to a work item and save it the field doesn't validate.

If I run the tests again (with the iteration already created) the same code succeeds.

Does anybody know how to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

This fixed it for me:

```
WorkItemStore wis = (WorkItemStore)tfsTeamProjColl.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
wis.RefreshCache();
wis.SyncToCache();
```

Maybe it will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced exactly the same behavior, and unfortunately @JWC answer didn't help. The solution which works for me can be found by [this link](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Question/smitha-solved-problem-call-549684.aspx).

So, this is a quick summary in case the original answer gets lost.

The key point is to use `WorkItemServer` class. It lives in the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.dll` assembly.

First of all, you create a `WorkItemStore` instance:

```
var store = collection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
```

Then, create necessary iteration paths:

```
var commonservice = collection.GetService<ICommonStructureService>();

var iterationRoot = commonservice.GetNodeFromPath("\\MyTeamProject\\Iteration");
var newIterationPath = commonservice.CreateNode("my sprint", iterationRoot.Uri);
```

Next, refresh the cache in TFS (I suspect this is similar to pressing `F5` in web interface):

```
var wiServer = collection.GetService<WorkItemServer>();
wiServer.SyncExternalStructures(WorkItemServer.NewRequestId(), commonservice.GetProjectFromName("MyTeamProject").Uri);
store.RefreshCache();
```

And finally, assign newly created work item to the newly created iteration:

```
var wi = new WorkItem(store.Projects["MyTeamProject"].WorkItemTypes["Product Backlog Item"]);

wi.Title = "Hello from API";
wi.Description = "This work item was created from API";
wi.Fields["Assigned To"].Value = "Yan Sklyarenko";

wi.IterationPath = FormatPath(commonservice.GetNode(newIterationPath).Path, "Iteration", "MyTeamProject");

wi.Save();
```

That's it! The method `FormatPath` translates the iteration path to the form required by the work item `IterationPath` field, that is from `\MyTeamProject\Iteration\my sprint` to `MyTeamProject\my sprint`.

Hope this can save some time.

NOTE: I run this towards TFS 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely running into a caching issue.  Try clearing the cache after you create the iteration.  A couple things you could try:

1. Get a new copy of the WorkItemStore.
2. Disconnect and reconnect to TFS
3. Check to see if there's a "refresh" method on either the WIS or on the TFS server objects.  I've shut down my dev instance of TFS for the night, and I don't recall if there's anything like it.

If that's not quite it, post your code and I'll see if I can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. I created Areapath and then created a query where the AreaPath was used. I did call store.RefreshCashe() but it did not work. Only in Debugger when I run store.RefreshCashe() two times manually.
Thanks "Yan Sklyarenko". I tried your Suggestion and it works fine (TFS Server 2012).